# Database is locked

Tags: android, java, sqlite

Всем привет. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что нужно обновить структуру базы в приложении. 
Что нужно сделать:
1)Добавить два столбца.
2) Удалить элементы с TYPE = 1. С остальными TYPE оставить.
3)Записать новые данные с TYPE = 1. 
Сделал такой код.

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        if (newVersion == 2){
            db.delete(SQLITE_TABLE, TYPE + "='1'" , null);
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + SQLITE_TABLE + " ADD COLUMN " + FIRST_NAME + " STRING");
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + SQLITE_TABLE + " ADD COLUMN " + LAST_NAME + " STRING");

        }

    }
```

В главной Activity (которая запускается при открытии приложения) сразу после открытия приложения идет запись в базу с TYPE = 1.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой - при первом запуске приложение вылетает с такой ошибкой:

```
11-14 23:49:40.560  26481-26481/com.example.android E/SQLiteLog﹕ (5) database is locked
11-14 23:49:40.630  26481-26481/com.example.android E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Failed to open database '/data/data/com.example.android/databases/TestData'.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5):
```

При повторном открытии приложения - все окей. И данные записались и приложение не вылетает. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема. Первый раз столкнулся с обновлением структуры в БД.

Answer (score 1):

После удаления записей завершите транзакцию и только потом запускайте `ALTER TABLE`